# building opencv3 with ros kinetic

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, opencv3, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have the default ros kinetic installed from the package manager. I get the following error when I try to compile my nodes with `imgproc` and `highgui` include.

Here is the relevant parts of my CMakeLists.txt file

```
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)
add_executable(cv_qt_ros 
    src/cv_qt_ros.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(cv_qt_ros
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} 
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
  ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Here is the compilation error: `No rule to make target 'opencv_calib3d-NOTFOUND', needed by '../devel/lib/cv_pose/cv_qt_ros'.  Stop.`

This is the output of the cmake variables:

```
-- OpenCV include directories /opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.3.1;/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.3.1/opencv
-- OpenCV libraries opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_viz;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cvv;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto;opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_viz;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cvv;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto
```

There are some similar questions but they do not address this specific case:
[question1](https://answers.ros.org/question/256850/opencv-with-ros-kinetic/), [question2](https://answers.ros.org/question/229246/how-to-build-opencv-extra-module-while-opencv-is-installed-with-ros/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281955/building-opencv3-with-ros-kinetic/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2018-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like something is broken on the OpenCV end. Here is the ROS discourse thread started couple months back: https://discourse.ros.org/t/opencv-3-3-1-is-breaking-builds-in-kinetic/3384?u=tfoote

And here are some temporary solutions on the github issue page: https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/193

I just used one of those solutions. I haven't dug into the details of why the problem exists. When I do, I will update this answer.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2018-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0